# apriori get the list of all items appear in rhs (best with frequency)

Tags: r, apriori

I want to have a list of item name which in the rhs of apriori with how many number of rules with it

we can use data(Groceries) for example

````
```
rules <- apriori (Groceries, 
              parameter = list(supp = 0.001, conf = 0.5)
              ) 
```
````

how there is a way to find out the complete list of items are list in rhs in this rules. if we can also have how many rules in this 'rules' related to each item will be best
this is not item frequency is how many rules have the rhs = 'item'
e.g.

{whole milk}  2345
{rolls/buns}   5
  .......

Comment: The function `apriori()`, as well as `data(Groceries)`, are not in base R. What package(s) are you using? Also, the form I see used with `apriori()` doesn't seem to have a left or right hand side. Where is the lhs-rhs format/model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code counts the number of rules for each unique item in the RHS by converting the RHS into a (sparse) 0-1 matrix and summing the 1s for each row (item).

```
library(arules)
data(Groceries)
rules <- apriori (Groceries, parameter = list(supp = 0.001, conf = 0.5))

rowSums(as(rhs(rules), "ngCMatrix"))
```